# Почему иногда возвращает пустую строку file_get_contents или fgets?

Tags: php

Почему иногда возвращает пустую строку  `file_get_contents` или `fgets`?

В данном случае, будем рассматривать функцию `fgets`.

Было проверено с **http** и **https** протоколом, происходит одно и тоже. Правда как
    показалось, с **http** работает боле стабильно, но всё равно, рано или
    поздно возвращает пустую строку. 
Проверялось без файла **.htaccess**,чтобы исключить дополнительные варианты возникновения ошибки.

**Чтобы вызвать ошибку**, нужно перейти на адрес этой страницы, код который я выкладываю, несколько раз подряд, меняя при этом значение переменной **number** в **GET** запросе.

---

**Вот пример**:

**Шаг 1**.
http://myhost/1/index.php?number

**Шаг 2**.
http://myhost/1/index.php?number

**Шаг 3**. Вот на этом шаге **fgets** уже может выдать пустую строку, но если не выдало пустую строку, пробуем дальше менять переменную в **GET** запросе
http://myhost/1/index.php?number=194

**Шаг 4**. 
http://myhost/1/index.php?number=19

**Шаг 5**. 
http://myhost/1/index.php?number=1

**Шаг 6**. 
http://myhost/1/index.php?number=

**Шаг 7**. 
http://myhost/1/index.php?number

**Шаг 8**. 
http://myhost/1/index.php?number=195

.... и.т.д

Когда **fgets** выдаёт пустую строку, то **fopen** в этом время выдаёт это -

`resource(199) of type (stream)`, то есть, судя по всему, это наверное нормально для **fopen**, но до конца я не уверен.

---

**Кот код**:

```
<?php

$a2 = $_GET['number'];
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

        for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            //Проверяем, есть ли этот файл
            if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/cahe.json')){

                $fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/cahe.json', "r" );
                if($fp == false || $fp == ''){
                    return var_dump("============= ОШИБКА ==============");
                }
                $mytext = '-';
                while (!feof($fp))
                {
                    $mytext = fgets($fp, 999);
                }
                if($mytext == ''){

                    var_dump($mytext);
                    return var_dump($fp);
                }
                $json_data =  json_decode($mytext, true);
                fclose($fp);



                $c = $json_data['count_m'] + 1;
                $data = '{"count":"1", "count_m":"'.$c.'"}';

                $fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/cahe.json', "w" );
                fwrite($fp, $data);
                fclose($fp);
            }else{
               return var_dump("============= ФАЙЛА НЕТУ ==============");
            }
      } 
}
```

---

**Примечание***
Если, переходить напрямую на эту страницу, без передачи переменной в **GET** запросе

http://myhost/1/index.php

**И**,убрать этот кусок кода:

```
$a2 = $_GET['number'];
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){}
```

То все работает стабильно (*НЕ РАБОТАЕТ СТАБИЛЬНО, ЗАПИСЫВАЕТ В ФАЙЛ КАК ПОПАЛО, ПРОСТО ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА НЕ ВЫВОДИТСЯ*).

Вот код2 (тоже нестабильный)

```
      for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {

           $data = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/cahe.json');
            $json_data =  json_decode($data, true);

            if($data == false || $data == ''){
                return var_dump($data.'   - '.$i.'    $number-'.$number);
            }else{
                $count_index = $json_data['count_index'];
                $count_index = $count_index + 1;
                $data = '{"count":"1", "count_index":"'.$count_index.'"}';


                // Флаг LOCK_EX для предотвращения записи данного файла кем-нибудь другим в данное время
                file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/cahe.json', $data, LOCK_EX); 
            }
   }
```

Comment: Честно пытался найти где у вас в этом куске используется нет параметр number или что то чувствительное к типу метода запроса, но не нашёл. И так и не понял сакральный смысл цикла на 1000 итераций...

Comment: @fens За каждый проход в цикле, добавляется новая запись в файл - `'{"count":"1", "count_m":"'.$c.'"}'; `   Вы всё правильно прочитали, переменная `number` не используется. Она просто стоит там для исследования, для того чтобы показать этот баг или ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на банальный race condition, состояние гонки. В конце каждой из 1000 итераций цикла вы открываете файл с модификатором `w`. Т.е. открыть файл на запись, указатель поставить на начало файла, обрезать файл до нулевой длины. Параллельный поток во время между `fopen(..., 'w')` и до `fwrite` будет получать файл нулевой длины.

Да, файловые функции не блокируют другие операции над этим же файлом. Вообще никак не блокируют. Можно запросто писать один файл в два потока и получить в итоге полнейшее как повезёт.

Для конкурентной обработки одного файла захватывайте рекомендательную блокировку [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php). Лишний раз обращаю внимание - блокировка рекомендательная. Вы обязаны её проверять всегда и везде при работе с этим файлом.

Для чтения файла захватывайте `LOCK_SH`, для записи `LOCK_EX`. Для перезаписи файла (!) вы должны:

1. открыть файл в режиме чтения и записи `r+`
2. захватить пишущую блокировку `LOCK_EX`
3. прочитать файл
4. изменить данные в памяти
5. очистить файл вызовом `ftruncate`
6. записать новые данные
7. сделать `fflush`
8. и лишь только потом отпустить блокировку
9. закрыть дескриптор вызовом `fclose`

Иначе будете терять данные.

Кто сказал, что работа с файликами - это просто? Конкурентный доступ к файлику - это кладезь интересных граблей и великолепный способ убить производительность конкурентных запросов. Это пока ещё не дошли до вопроса, что делать, если скрипт почему-то упал в момент между `ftruncate` но до `fwrite` и прочие прелести восстановления после сбоя.

---

Как тут можно словить race condition, заходя последовательно на конкретный явно локальный url браузером - есть варианты. Например, браузер может отправлять два запроса вместо одного. Или ещё что-нибудь запрашивать, хоть фавиконку, а та случайно отсуствует и реврайтится и передаётся фронт-контролеру index.php. Или ещё чего логичное, но что не придёт в голову, пока об этом не узнаешь.

Comment: Я сделаю всё что Вы написали, и отпишусь Вам. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ничё себе! Точно, все работает как часы, всё стабильно. Вот это да. Как GET запрос с переменной мог на это повлиять? Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Переменная в GET запросе ни при чем, точнее она как бы выявляет, показывает ошибку, но больше не к чему не относится. Просто если посылать запрос с одним и тем-же значением переменной, то ошибку видно не будет, не будет `fgets` выдавать пустую строку. Но при этом, данные будут теряться при записи в файл.  Этот ответ правильный! Большое Вам спасибо.

Comment: А как же быть с `file_put_contents` и `file_put_contents` они работают нестабильно. Их код я добавил в свой вопрос.

Comment: А если открыть не `w`, а `a`?

Comment: Как это получается - повторюсь, надо разбираться с браузером. В какой-то момент отправляется лишний запрос и получается конкурентное выполнение в два потока.

file_get_contents - мне немного лениво искать по исходникам механизма stream, но вроде он блокировки вообще не трогает. А блокировка рекомендательная, если её не проверять то будут фокусы.

@Qwertiy ничего не изменится. Алгоритм без потерянных обновлений тот же. Другое дело, если вам и нужно поведение дозаписи в конец файла, при том без чтения предыдущих данных.

Comment: Вы бы не могли ответить на почти точно такой же вопрос, который я описал вот тут  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601798/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB

Comment: Похоже там проблема с этим - `filesize(__DIR__.'/cahe.json')` . Если вместо этой функции поставить допустим 2000, то все работает стабильно, как мне кажется.