# Как правильно считывать информацию и после, записывать её в текстовый файл?

Tags: php

Как правильно считывать информацию и после, записывать её в текстовый файл?

Я пытасю это делать как описано в нижиследующем тексте, но судя по всему, образуется **race condition**. 
Допустим, если в цикле будет всего две итерации, то этот код отработает хорошо.

Смотрите:

Файл 
**cahe.json** есть в системе и содержит изначальную запись

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"0"}
```

---

**Используем вариатн A** с двумя итерациями `for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {`

на выходе получаем в файле запись

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"2"}
```

---

**Используем вариатн B** с тысячей итераций `for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {`

на выходе получаем в файле запись

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"01"}
```

вместо

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"1000"}
```

---

**Используем вариатн C** с тысячей итераций `for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {`, **но** меняем начальное значение в файле **cahe.json**

**с**

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"0"}
```

**на**

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"1000"}
```

на **выходе получаем** в файле запись

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"2000"}
```

---

**Используем вариант D** с тысячей итераций `for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {`  **и плюс**, убираем кусочек кода `filesize(__DIR__.'/cahe.json')`, заменяя его вот на этот - '20000', допустим

на выходе получаем в файле запись

```
{"count":"1", "count_1":"1000"}
```

---

**//КОД**

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
//------------------------------------------------
      $json_data;
            $contents = '';
            $fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/cahe.json', "c+" );
            if($fp == false){
              //была ошибка
              var_dump("Была ошибка при открытии файла");
            }else{
                if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // выполняем эксклюзивную блокировку
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    $contents = fread($fp, filesize(__DIR__.'/cahe.json'));
                    $json_data =  json_decode($contents, true);
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    ftruncate($fp, 0); // очищаем файл
                    //перемещаем файловый указаттель в начало файла
                    fseek($fp, 0);
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    $count_1 = $json_data['count_1'] + 1;
                    $data = '{"count":"1", "count_1":"'.$count_1.'"}';
                    fwrite($fp, $data);
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    fflush($fp);        // очищаем вывод перед отменой блокировки
                    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // отпираем файл
                } else {
                    var_dump("Не удалось получить блокировку!");
                }
                fclose($fp);
            }

//------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: @Jean-Claude А как делать не тупо? Разве есть какие то другие варианты?

Comment: Вне цикла открыли, по окончанию цикла закрыли. Всего 1 раз. Или file_get_contents() и file_put_contents(), по 1 разу.

Comment: Так не получится, файлы могут быть разные. Это раз. Два, с `file_get_contents()` в связи с `file_get_contents()` образуются конкурирующи потоки и на выходе будет происходить частичная потеря данных.

Comment: @Jean-Claude  можно написать и `text` просто. В чем разница? Там все таки `json` хранится а не просто текст.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее. Совсем непонятно зачем вам использовать файловую систему. Откуда взялись конкурирующие потоки? Что вам нужно получить в итого? Вы явно взяли не то решение для своей задачи

Comment: @ArchDemon ну я как бы максимально подробно описал её да ещй с примерами и кодом. Зачем мне использовать файловую систему - я не понимаю, как этот вопрос может решить тот который я задал. Откуда взялись конкурирующие потоки - это предположение, похоже на это потому что.  Вы явно взяли не то решение для своей задачи - да спасибо, это сильно поможет в ответе на тот вопрос который я задал.

Comment: Вот поэтому вам никто помочь и не может. Задача не ясна. Тот пример, что вы продемонстрировали ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: неправильно у вас пашет filesize(), когда цифра до 9, считывает 28 байтов, когда записали 10, считывает опять же 28 символов, а не 29, поэтому json не может считать данные и обнуляет.

Comment: @ArchDemon   Здачу я описал это Раз. Два: мне уже помогли в почти такомже вопросе и я сам себе кажется тоже помог или почти помог я щеё до конца не знаю, все не просто я в лгком недовольтсве от этого всего

Comment: `я не понимаю, как этот вопрос может решить тот который я задал` - я бы порекомендовал вам всё же ответить на уточняющие вопросы. Есть вероятность того, что вы чего-то не знаете (ведь именно поэтому вы здесь, правда?), а спрашивающие знают или предполагают. И поэтому, чтобы помочь - уточняют некоторые вещи. Не стоит это игнорировать и принимать в штыки, если **только вы** не понимаете зачем эти уточняющие данные нужны ;-)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский есть вероятность с размером в 100% что все чего-то не знают. Нельзя идеально ничего знать, особенно в языках программирования. Это для вас новость? Спасибо за рекомендации. В этих рекомендациях есть смысл. Но в данном случае, я думаю что всё делаю правильно. Не важно с какой целью мне нужно выполнить поставленную задачу, есть задачи выполнимые а есть не выполнимые. Так вот прежде всего, нужно определиться с этим, выполняемая ли эта задача или нет. Задачу я описал подробно.  И тут не уместна просьба : Опишите задачу подробнее. Совсем непонятно зачем вам использовать файлов..

Comment: `в данном случае, я думаю что всё делаю правильно` >>>>>> думать и знать - это разные вещи. Если вы **думаете** (т.е. предполагаете), что знаете, то это не значит, что это абсолютно верно... А если вы **знаете**, тогда этого вопроса тут бы не было и вашего первого предложения в вопросе: `Как правильно считывать информацию и после, записывать её в текстовый файл?` тоже не было бы...... выглядит смешно: помогите, я тону.... да чё ты руки свои ко мне тянешь? да че ты мне тут круг резиновый кидаешь? да я умею плавать!....но я тонууу, спасите

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Есть вопросы по существу, а есть, нет. Тот вопрос был не по существу.

Comment: @gilo1212 ясно) вы в своем репертуаре))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Ну спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

неправильно у вас пашет filesize(), когда цифра до 9, считывает 28 байтов, когда записали 10, считывает опять же 28 символов, а не 29, поэтому json не может считать данные и обнуляет.

В доках http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filesize.php

> Замечание: Результаты этой функции кэшируются. Более подробную информацию смотрите в разделе clearstatcache().

Для чистки кеша необходимо выполнение функции clearstatcache().